# Display: none; Causing Width Issues

Tags: jquery, function

I have a jQuery script that makes it so that it displays Please Wait, for 3 seconds, then displays a DIV. Now the issue I'm having is that when I do display: none; it is causing width and height of my other div's to distort. Is there another method of hiding the div during the function that may not disrupt?

jQuery used

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#loading").hide(100); //100 = animation speed in miliseconds
    $("#quickstats").show(100);
}, 3000); //3000 miliseconds = 3 seconds​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Can you show us your problem using http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I'll try, the issue where the width and height is getting distorted is within another jquery function.

Comment: You could try setting it to `visibility:hidden;` instead of none. This will hide it without removing the div from the layout.

Comment: @mrtsherman       That seems to be working better, but how do I change the visibility to shown after the timer has been up?

Comment: @user1698088  - try setting it to `visibility:visible;`

Comment: @mrtsherman  Well I know, but how in jQuery do I set it to change the visibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the #loading DIV and #quickstats DIV have the same width, you can try:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#loading").animate({opacity: 0}, 100, function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $("#quickstats").css({opacity: 0}).show().animate({opacity: 1}, 100);
    });
}, 3000);
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/XUSM2/

**Demo (on page load):** http://jsfiddle.net/XUSM2/1/

Comment: When I did this, the content I'm waiting to load never was hidden.

Comment: Now how do I make it automated? I'm extremely new to Javascript/jQuery

Comment: It is animated, is it not? The opcaity is being animated. Do you want to animate any other property (width/height etc..) as well?

Comment: No I meant so that on page load, it does everything by itself no buttons needed.

Comment: I put it in the button just so that you can see clearly how it is working. You can put that code in your `.ready()` handler for doing it on page load.

Comment: This works now, but my issue is that it goes VERY fast. Like half a second.

Comment: You can adjust the speed of the animation by replacing the `'slow'` in the animate call with your desired duration - for ex: 3000 (for 3 seconds). `x.animate({...}, 3000, ...)` instead of `x.animate({...}, 'slow', ...)`

Comment: I did this, set it to 50000 just to test it wasn't me. And its still going very fast http://jsfiddle.net/XUSM2/3/

Comment: Sorry, Fixed it, set the quickstats div's style to opacity 0.

Comment: Got it all working =] Thank you so much for dealing with my Javascript insolence lol

Answer (score 2):

You can use `visibilty` instead of `display` css property. Otherwise you will want to go about it a different way. There are several options depending on your page layout.

```
visibility:hidden;
visibility:visible;
```

You could also wrap the timer inside of another element and hide that instead. In this case I added a span around your timer. You can then use the direct descendent selector `>` in your selector for hiding.

```
<div id="loading"><span>Timer</span></div>

setTimeout(function(){
    $("#loading > span").hide(100); //100 = animation speed in miliseconds
    $("#quickstats").show(100);
}, 3000); //3000 miliseconds = 3 seconds​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: This just sits at Timer in the span